# ReactJS: Why isn't my component's state changing with new props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a header with links that each lead to a different gallery viewer, so I want each gallery to exhibit a unique default large image upon rendering. The parent component below is responsible for obtaining the index of the gallery that was clicked from a child component and passes an image to another child.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

      onViewIndex: -1,
      defaultImageLarge: "./images/sala-large/04_sl02_BB.jpg"
    }

    this.handlePickerClick = this.handlePickerClick.bind(this);

  }

  handlePickerClick(index) {

    this.setState({onViewIndex: index});

    if(index == 1) {

      this.setState({defaultImageLarge: "./images/sala-large/04_sl02_BB.jpg"});
      console.log("changed large image to sala");

    }

    else if(index == 2) {

      this.setState({defaultImageLarge: "./images/qto-large/04_qt01_BB.jpg"});
      console.log("changed large image to " + this.state.defaultImageLarge);

    }

    else if(index == 3) {

      this.setState({defaultImageLarge: "./images/hall-large/04_det03_BB.jpg"});
      console.log("changed large image to " + this.state.defaultImageLarge);

    }

    else if(index == 4) {

      this.setState({defaultImageLarge: "./images/ban-large/04_ban01_BB.jpg"});
      console.log("changed large image to " + this.state.defaultImageLarge);

    }

  }

  render() {
    return (

        <div id = "page-container" align = "center">

          <Header />
          <Banner />
          <div className = "section-header"><h2 className = "section-header-text">PORTFOLIO</h2></div>
          <GalleryPicker onClick = {this.handlePickerClick}/>
          <GalleryView onView = {this.state.onViewIndex} imageLarge = {this.state.defaultImageLarge}/>

        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

My GalleryView component receives the correct image from the imageLarge prop, but won't update its state with it:

```
class GalleryView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.getImageList = this.getImageList.bind(this);
        this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            imageLarge: this.props.imageLarge
        }
    }

    changeImage(address) {

        this.setState({imageLarge: address})
    }

    getImageList(index) {

        //SALAS
        if(index == 1) {

            return (

                <div>

                    <div id = "gallery-list-container">

                        <ul className = "list-view">

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/04_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/04_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/04_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/04_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/04_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/04_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/05_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/05_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/05_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/05_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/13_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/13_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/13_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/13_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/13_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/13_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/13_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/13_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/13_sl05_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/13_sl05_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                        <br/>

                        <ul className = "list-view">

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/14_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/14_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/14_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/14_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/14_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/14_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/15_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/15_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/15_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/15_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/15_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/15_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/16_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/16_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/16_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/16_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/16_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/16_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/sala-small/16_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/sala-large/16_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <ImageOnView imgSrc = {this.state.imageLarge} />

                </div>

                );

        }

        //QUARTOS
        else if(index == 2) {

            alert(this.props.imageLarge);
            alert(this.state.imageLarge);

            return (

                <div>

                    <div id = "gallery-list-container">

                        <ul className = "list-view">

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/qto-small/04_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/qto-large/04_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/qto-small/04_qt02_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/qto-large/04_qt02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/qto-small/14_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/qto-large/14_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/qto-small/16_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/qto-large/16_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/qto-small/17_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/qto-large/17_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <ImageOnView imgSrc = {this.state.imageLarge} />

                </div>

                );
        }

        //HALL
        else if(index == 3) {

            alert(this.props.imageLarge);

            return (

                <div>

                    <div id = "gallery-list-container">

                        <ul className = "list-view">

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/04_det03_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/04_det03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/04_det04_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/04_det04_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/16_det03_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/16_det03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/17_det01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/17_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/18_det01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/18_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <br/>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/04_ee01_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/04_ee01_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/05_ee02_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/05_ee02_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/05_ee03_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/05_ee03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                            <li className = "list-view-item">
                                    <img src = {require("./images/hall-small/14_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                                    onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/hall-large/14_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <ImageOnView imgSrc = {this.state.imageLarge} />

                </div>

                );          
        }

        //BANHEIROS
        else if(index == 4) {


            return (

                <div>

                <div id = "gallery-list-container">

                    <ul className = "list-view">

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_ban03_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_ban03_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_ban04_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_ban04_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_ban05_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_ban05_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_det01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <br/>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_det02_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_det02_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/04_det09_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/04_det09_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/14_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/14_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                        <li className = "list-view-item">
                                <img src = {require("./images/ban-small/18_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                                onClick = {() => this.changeImage('./images/ban-large/18_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <ImageOnView imgSrc = {this.state.imageLarge} />

                </div>

                );          
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (

                <div>

                    <div id = "gallery-view-container">

                        {this.getImageList(this.props.onView)}

                    </div>

                </div>
            );

    }
}
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Can you share `GalleryView` code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the state when prop has changes, or use prop directly without to create a local state...

Take a look at:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Better to use `deriveStateFromProps` since `componentWillReceiveProps` is now deprecated.

Comment: Well, I am passing the component's prop to the state. I know the prop is changing, so shouldn't that automatically change the state?

Comment: @RodrigoVeiga You're doing that in the constructor, that means it will only happen the first time.

Comment: This componentWillReceiveProps method seems to fit my problem here... any tips on how I might go about it?

Comment: As @Anas said, it is better to use the deriveStateFromProps hook, you can read more about it at: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

But, you can use the prop directly too.
Just use `this.props.imageLarge`, instead `this.state.imageLarge`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
class GalleryView extends Component {

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.imageLarge !== prevState.imageLarge) {
        return {
            imageLarge: nextProps.imageLarge,
            ..
        };
    }

    return null;
  }

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.getImageList = this.getImageList.bind(this);
    this.changeImage = this.changeImage.bind(this);

    this.state = {

        imageLarge: this.props.imageLarge
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes images change whenever I choose a new gallery, but now I can't switch between images in a gallery, which I could do before. Is the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method supposed to execute even when props haven't changed? If so, it won't work here

Comment: In the `getDerivedStateFromProps`, you have access to next Props, so you can compare nextProps with this.props and only update the state if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 2 states which are not synchronised properly. You have some options. You can use getDerivedStatesFropProps of course; but I will change the child to a functional component to use the state of the parent so that whenever the state of the parent changes, the child is re-rendered and automatically updated. That way you don't need to synchronise two states since you will have only one.

In the parent

```
<GalleryView getImageList={this.getImageList} changeImage={this.changeImage} imageLarge = {this.state.defaultImageLarge} index={this.state.onViewIndex} onView = {this.state.onViewIndex}  />
```

And the child

```
GalleryView = (getImageList, changeImage, imageLarge, index, onView) => {
//SALAS
if (index == 1) {

    return (

        <div>

            <div id="gallery-list-container">

                <ul className="list-view">

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/04_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/04_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/04_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/04_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/04_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/04_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/05_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/05_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/05_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/05_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/13_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/13_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/13_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/13_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/13_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/13_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/13_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/13_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/13_sl05_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/13_sl05_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <br/>

                <ul className="list-view">

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/14_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/14_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/14_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/14_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/14_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/14_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/15_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/15_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/15_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/15_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/15_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/15_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/16_sl01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/16_sl01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/16_sl02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/16_sl02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/16_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/16_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/sala-small/16_sl04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/sala-large/16_sl04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <ImageOnView imgSrc={imageLarge}/>

        </div>

    //QUARTOS
    );

} else if (index == 2) {

    alert(imageLarge);
    alert(imageLarge);

    return (

        <div>

            <div id="gallery-list-container">

                <ul className="list-view">

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/qto-small/04_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/qto-large/04_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/qto-small/04_qt02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/qto-large/04_qt02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/qto-small/14_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/qto-large/14_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/qto-small/16_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/qto-large/16_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/qto-small/17_qt01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/qto-large/17_qt01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <ImageOnView imgSrc={imageLarge}/>

        </div>

    //HALL
    );
} else if (index == 3) {

    alert(imageLarge);

    return (

        <div>

            <div id="gallery-list-container">

                <ul className="list-view">

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/04_det03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/04_det03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/04_det04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/04_det04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/16_det03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/16_det03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/17_det01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/17_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/18_det01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/18_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <br/>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/04_ee01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/04_ee01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/05_ee02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/05_ee02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/05_ee03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/05_ee03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/hall-small/14_sl03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/hall-large/14_sl03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <ImageOnView imgSrc={imageLarge}/>

        </div>

    //BANHEIROS
    );
} else if (index == 4) {

    return (

        <div>

            <div id="gallery-list-container">

                <ul className="list-view">

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_ban03_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_ban03_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_ban04_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_ban04_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_ban05_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_ban05_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_det01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_det01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <br/>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_det02_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_det02_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/04_det09_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/04_det09_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/14_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/14_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                    <li className="list-view-item">
                        <img
                            src={require("./images/ban-small/18_ban01_SS.jpg")}
                            onClick=
                            {() => changeImage.bind(this,'./images/ban-large/18_ban01_BB.jpg')}/>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <ImageOnView imgSrc={imageLarge}/>

        </div>

    );
}

return (

    <div>

        <div id="gallery-view-container">

            {getImageList(onView)}

        </div>

    </div>
);
}
```

I think your code needs further review though.